# How does one calculate the derivative of $a^{g(x)}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for $a=3$, $g(x)=-(x^2-4x+1)$

Tags: derivatives

Prove that $\frac{d}{d x}\left(3^{-\left(x^{2}-4 x+1\right)}\right)=-2 \times 3^{-x^{2}+4 x-1}(x-2) \log (3)$

How does one calculate the derivative of $a^{g(x)}$ where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for $a=3$, $g(x)=-(x^2-4x+1)$

I tried

$f^{\prime}(x) \equiv \lim _{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ and then took logs.

I heard that $\dfrac{d}{dx}(a^x)=a^xln(a)$ and this is a more general case.

Comment: Just use the chain rule.  As $[a^x]' = a^x\ln x$ and $[f(g(x))]' = f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ we have $[a^{g(x)}]' = [a^{g^{x}}]'\cdot g'(x) =( a^{g'(x)}\ln a)\cdot g'(x)$.

Comment: You probably want to be consistant in your notation.  Decide if you are going to use $\ln$ or $\log$ for the natural logarithm and decide if you are going to Legrange's notation for derivative ($f'(x)$) or if you are going to use Leibniz' ($\frac d{dx}f(x)$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would comment instead but I do not have enough reputation to do that so.

Firstly, if $\frac{d}{dx}\left[e^{x}\right]=e^{x}$ then $\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^{x}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{\ln a^{x}}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(e^{x\ln a}\right)=\ln ae^{x\log_{e}a}=a^{x}\ln a$

Hopefully that clears the fact that $\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^{x}\right)=a^{x}\ln a$

Now, by chainrule $\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^{g\left(x\right)}\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(a^{g\left(x\right)}\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)$

If you are not aware of what chainrule is, it essentially states that $\frac{d}{dx}\left[f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right]=f'\left(g\left(x\right)\right)g'\left(x\right)$.